Cannot add files to .gitignore in React application repository
I am using VS code with the Git extensions to manage version control and push/pull commits to my repository. I am creating a React application that has a public folder, a node_modules folder, an src folder. At the same level, I have my .gitignore file. In .gitignore, I have added the /node_modules folder like this:
# dependencies
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js

This works and none of the packages in my app get picked up as Changes when I add them. I also have added a data folder under the public directory. I have put some test data to use for development (my_test.csv). However when I try to add /public/data to gitignore, I still see the  my_test.csv file under Changes. Is there something I am leaving off? I also tried adding '.csv', 'my_test.csv', '/public/data.my_test.csv' all to no avail. I also use the command Clear Search History to clear the cache.

When you say that my_test.csv appears under changes, does it appear under untracked files or tracked files?

Are you sure Clear Search History clears Git cache/index?

It appears under tracked changes. And no, I am not sure that Clear Search History does the same as git rm --cache (I couldn't get that command to work), but thought that was the equivalent of clearing the cache.
